Limit keystore access to specific processes
Is there a way to limit the keystore access for processes within the same app, I mean, If a process created a key entry, this entry can't be accessed by other processes even it it belongs to the same app?

Android restricts access to AndroidKeystore entries to the app that has created them. Of course this only works as long as the system security is not broken e.g. by rooting.

If I understood you correctly and assuming your key is a String type, what you can do is:
Create a class, say KeyHandler:
public class KeyHandler{

     // Singleton design pattern needed, not part of the code here

     static Map<Integer, String> keysHolder = new HashMap<>();

     public void addEntry(Integer entryID){
     // add key here
     }

     public void getValue(Integer keyOfDictionary)
     {
     // return the String value (which is your keystore) according to the Integer
     }  
}

And when you want to use it, if you want a run-time security measure, you can create in any class that needs to use this a random Integer as it's key and add it to the class. Something such as:
// Where you define your class's members        
static private int mEntryRandomKey = -1;

// In your init part:
         if(mEntryRandomKey == -1){
            Random random = new Random();
            mEntryRandomKey = random.nextInt();
    KeyHandler.getInstance().addEntry(mEntryRandomKey)
}

I'm not on my PC to write a proper code but this should get you at least in the direction you need. Of course, the whole point for this to work is that in the KeyHandler class you reject any call made by an ID that does not exist and only the ID that was create by a specific class can be accessed via by an object of that class.
Note - This piece of code ignores the almost-0 chance of generating same random key by 2 different classes, if you don't want to ignore that case you can add another "isKeyTaken" in keyHandler class and assuming you luckily (or unluckily, depends how you look at it) generated the same random number, simply generate a new one)
